# К какому разряду относится наречие "вызывающе"?

Tags: наречия

Мое понимание:

наречие образовано от причастия "*вызывающий*", есть сравнительная степень "*более вызывающе*". Поэтому, мне кажется, оно должно относиться к разряду определительных качественных наречии. Но мой учитель утверждает, что оно относится к разряду определительных способа и образа действия, так как отвечает на вопрос "*каким образом?*".

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: 1. "Это вызывающе!" - а тут на какой вопрос отвечает наречие? Тут ведь уже не "каким образом", верно? 2. Рискну предложить такую классификацию (мое понимание). Все наречия произошедшие от причастий являются описанием действий, а все наречия произошедшие от прилагательных - описанием качеств.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, @user190920 . Не знаю, прояснит ли это что-нибудь или наоборот запутает, но здесь утверждается, что качественные наречия могут также происходить от причастий: https://goldrussian.ru/opredelitelnye-narechija.html

Comment: Классификации вообще дело мутное. А это мутная классификация. В грамматических вопросах есть базовый труд, на который худо-бедно можно опереться. И он относит наречие "быстро/быстрее" в разряд наречий образа действия, что противоречит вашей классификации. См параграф 1650. http://rusgram.narod.ru/1645-1668.html. В грамматике нет незыблемых истин, и не всегда стоит во всем доходить до конца. Учтите этот совет на будущее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Вызывающе*** – это **качественное** определительное наречие.

**Пояснение**

1. Об этом сказано **[в словаре](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=48&dicts%5B%5D=42).**  ***Вызыва́юще***. Наречие качественное.
2. Наречие образовано от качественного прилагательного ***вызывающий***: дерзкий, наглый, содержащий вызов.
3. Ничего от глагола ***вызвать*** здесь не осталось, так как сущ. ***вызов*** используется в **переносном** значении: как
   стремление, готовность вступить в спор.
4. Наречия **способа и образа действия** обозначают, каким способом или образом протекает действие: *бегом, пешком, вприпрыжку, вручную.* К ним примыкают наречия **сравнения** (*по-детски, по-своему*) и наречия **совокупности** (*вереницей, поодиночке*).

**Из словаря**

**ВЫЗОВ**, -а; м.  3. Стремление, готовность вступить в спор, борьбу и т.п. (выраженное во взгляде, голосе, действиях и т.п.). В. коллективу, общественному мнению. Откровенный, прямой, дерзкий в. С вызовом посмотреть на кого-л. Бросить в. кому-л. (о поступке, идущем вразрез с общепринятыми нормами). Вызывной (см.).

**ВЫЗЫВАЮЩИЙ**, -ая, -ее. 1. Содержащий вызов (3 зн.); дерзкий, наглый. В. вид. В-ая поза. В-ая усмешка. В-ее поведение. 2. Обращающий на себя внимание излишней яркостью, нескромностью; броский. В. костюм. Вызывающе, нареч. Держать себя в.